# Android, directly open mtp folder

Tags: java, android, android-intent, mtp

I'm working on a project that requires the connection of a smartphone to a tablet via a USB cable. To acces the files from the smartphone from the tablet, I am using the Android's `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to retrieve the files. I am, more specifically trying to open pictures.

I know this is possible since, when I click on the notification describing the smartphone, it opens a default Android app with the base folder of the smartphone.

What I am trying to achieve is to directly open the connected smartphone's storage instead of having to switch from the tablet to storage to the smartphone's.

I know how to get the volume name of the smartphone but that hasn't helped me progress. I have checked the Uri, received from the Intent, it is something like `content://com.android.mtp.documents/document/951` or `content://com.android.mtp.documents/tree/1021`.

I have tried to use thes Uri to open the desired folder but it didn't work.
I've tried the new `StorageManager` API without success.

Recently, I've focused more on trying to simply access the files from my app but using the above mentionned Uri or the mount folder (`/dev/bus/usb/001/002/`) leads to nothing.
I also tried the `Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED` without success.

My current code it this:
Requesting permission to use the smartphone:

```
final UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
if (deviceList.size() > 0) {//TODO switch to 1 on USBCameraFragment
    PendingIntent mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) deviceList.values().toArray()[0];
    manager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please connect your device to the tablet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Opening the connection and starting the Intent:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
            synchronized (this) {
                UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                    if(device != null){
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

                        Uri path = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(device.getProductName());
                        //Uri path = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED).getAbsolutePath());

                        i.setDataAndType(path, "image/*");
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

                        MtpDevice mtpDevice = new MtpDevice(device);

                        UsbDeviceConnection conn = ((UsbManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE)).openDevice(device);
                        mtpDevice.open(conn);

                        //1.5s to make sure I have allowed the MTP connection on the smartphone.
                        try{Thread.sleep(1500);}catch(InterruptedException e){}

                        startActivityForResult(i, Constants.PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "permission denied for device: " + device);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE?

Comment: `have tried to use thes Uri to open the desired folder `. Those are uris for files. About which folder are you talking? And what did you try?

Comment: `Uri path = MediaStore.Files.......` What is the value of path.toString()?

Comment: `i.setDataAndType(path, "image/*");` Setting Data has no effect i think. Have you ever seen effect? Only Type has influence.

Comment: I have tried Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, it returned this Uri: `content://com.android.mtp.documents/tree/1021` (the base folder of the smartphone). I tried `content://com.android.mtp.documents/tree/1021` to open the base folder and `content://com.android.mtp.documents/document/951` to open a File, neither worked. MediaStore gives `content://media/SAMSUNG_Android/files`. Indeed, setting data did not change the directory (I checked with a directory on the tablet).

Comment: Apparently there is no way to specify an initial uri with sdk 24. This will be added in the next Android version with DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.html#EXTRA_INITIAL_URI)

Comment: `I tried content://com.android.mtp.documents/tree/1021 to open the base folder` I wonder what you tried. You cannot open it as if it was a file. The things you can do instead is using DocumentFile for instance to list dirs and files in it or create files in it or find files in it. Please show your code in a new code block. Not in a comment.

Comment: I tried both File and DocumentFile, neither worked. I don't have the code for those test since ti was a simple for loop.

Comment: File of course will not do. And try DocumentFile again. No reason it would not work. And you do not need a loop to see that it works.

Comment: I can create the DocumentFile but I cannot explore the folder and files on the smartphone using myDocumentFile.listFiles(), the method returns a null array

Comment: Mmmm strange. Sadly i cannot test this setup out.